# FHIR resource needed for capacity handling

Tags: hl7-fhir, capacity

I am trying to find an FHIR resource to carry the bookable capacity details to the end system.

The scenario is, an outpatient clinic session is running daily with 10 slots/day. It has an overbook capacity of 2.
So Overall 12 bookings can be performed/day. Assume there 3 bookings were performed and to update the end system with the details of 9 booking still allowed in the clinic using the GET API method.

Kindly suggest the appropriate resource for the above use case.

Thanks
Pattabi

Answer (score 1):

If you implement the Schedule and Slot resource types, someone can perform a GET request like this to request all of the open slots in a particular schedule:

```
GET <your_server>/Slot?schedule.actor=Practitioner/123&status=free
```

The Slot resource has an option to say it is overbooked. The Schedule has a link to the scarce resource(s) it is about (practitioner, location, equipment, etc.) and can also hold information about the type of service.

See http://www.hl7.org/fhir/schedule.html, http://www.hl7.org/fhir/slot.html, and also http://www.hl7.org/fhir/appointment.html for more information and workflow involved.